# Select records from concurrent dictionary using lambda

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

I have a concurrent dictionary with datetime as the key and integer value. every half hour there is a new entry and I have data for the past week, I would like to select the top integer value for specific days. any recommendations on how to do this?

Comment: Can the DateTime keys of your dictionary contain hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: yes DateTime does contain seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
var value = dictionary.Where(x => x.Key.Day == 5).Max(x=>x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to group the values in your concurrent dictionary by Date:

```
var dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<DateTime, int>();
dic[new DateTime(2015, 4, 5, 7, 0, 1)] = 1;
dic[new DateTime(2015, 4, 5, 7, 0, 2)] = 2;
dic[new DateTime(2015, 4, 5, 7, 0, 3)] = 3;
dic[new DateTime(2015, 4, 6, 7, 0, 1)] = 5;
dic[new DateTime(2015, 4, 6, 7, 0, 2)] = 6;
dic[new DateTime(2015, 4, 6, 7, 0, 3)] = 7;

var searchDay = new DateTime(2015, 4, 5);

// Find the values corresponding to the specified day
var dates = dic.GroupBy(item => item.Key.Date).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == searchDay.Date);
if (dates != null)
{
    int max = dates.Max(x => x.Value);
    // That's the maximum value for the specified day
}
```